# Google Earth API Moving a polygon

Tags: google-earth

I just starting coding with Google Earth using the GEPlugin control for .Net and still got a lot to learn.

What has got me puzzled is when I try to drag a polygon.

The method below is called whenever the mousemove event fires and should be moving each point of the polygon while retaining the orginal shape of the polygon. The lat / long for each point is changed but the polygon does not move position on the map.

Will moving a point in a polygon cause it to redraw, do I need to call a method to force a redraw or perhaps do something else entirely?

Thanks!

```
private void DoMouseMove(IKmlMouseEvent mouseEvent)
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            mouseEvent.preventDefault();

            var placemark = mouseEvent.getTarget() as IKmlPlacemark;

            if (placemark == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            IKmlPolygon polygon = placemark.getGeometry() as IKmlPolygon;


            if (polygon != null)
            {
                float latOffset = startLatLong.Latitude - mouseEvent.getLatitude();
                float longOffset = startLatLong.Longitude - mouseEvent.getLongitude();

                KmlLinearRingCoClass outer = polygon.getOuterBoundary();
                KmlCoordArrayCoClass coordsArray = outer.getCoordinates();

                for(int i = 0; i < coordsArray.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    KmlCoordCoClass currentPoint = coordsArray.get(i);
                    currentPoint.setLatLngAlt(currentPoint.getLatitude() + latOffset, 
                        currentPoint.getLongitude() + longOffset, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with a library to handle this below.

Answer (score 2):

Consider voting for these issues to be resolved

- http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/issues/detail?id=33
- http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=167

You may find some hints at the following link:

http://earth-api-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extensions/examples/ruler.html

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

I've released the extension library: https://bitbucket.org/mutopia/earth

See https://bitbucket.org/mutopia/earth/src/master/sample/index.html to run it.

See the [drag() method in the sample code class](https://bitbucket.org/mutopia/earth/src/2979afa5029009e6ae7c9709ed2f33d82f4cd3bb/Examples.js?at=master#cl-301), which calls `setDragMode()` and `addDragEvent()` to enable dragging of the `KmlPolygon`.

---

I successfully implemented this using [takeOverCamera](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsUtilReference#takeOverCamera%28enable%29) in the [earth-api-utility-library](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/) and three events:

```
setDragMode: function (mode) {
    // summary:
    //      Sets dragging mode on and off
    if (mode == this.dragMode) {
        Log.info('Drag mode is already', mode);
    } else {
        this.dragMode = mode;
        Log.info('Drag mode set', mode);
        if (mode) {
            this.addEvent(this.ge.getGlobe(), 'mousemove', this.dragMouseMoveCallback);
            this.addEvent(this.ge.getGlobe(), 'mouseup', this.dragMouseUpCallback);
            this.addEvent(this.ge.getView(), 'viewchange', this.dragViewChange, false);
        } else {
            this.removeEvent(this.ge.getGlobe(), 'mousemove', this.dragMouseMoveCallback);
            this.removeEvent(this.ge.getGlobe(), 'mouseup', this.dragMouseUpCallback);
            this.removeEvent(this.ge.getView(), 'viewchange', this.dragViewChange, false);
        }
    }
},
```

This is in a utility library within a much larger project. `dragMode` is a boolean which adds and removes events. These three events control what happens when you drag. `addEvent` and `removeEvent` are my own wrapper functions:

```
addEvent: function (targetObject, eventID, listenerCallback, capture) {
    // summary:
    //      Convenience method for google.earth.addEventListener
    capture = setDefault(capture, true);
    google.earth.addEventListener(targetObject, eventID, listenerCallback, capture);
},

removeEvent: function (targetObject, eventID, listenerCallback, capture) {
    // summary:
    //      Convenience method for google.earth.removeEventListener
    capture = setDefault(capture, true);
    google.earth.removeEventListener(targetObject, eventID, listenerCallback, capture);
},
```

Ignoring the minor details, all the important stuff is in the callbacks to those events. The `mousedown` event locks the camera and sets the polygon I'm dragging as the `dragObject` (it's just a variable I'm using). It saves the original lat long coordinates.

```
this.dragMouseDownCallback = lang.hitch(this, function (event) {
    var obj = event.getTarget();
    this.lockCamera(true);
    this.setSelected(obj);
    this.dragObject = obj;
    this.dragLatOrigin = this.dragLatLast = event.getLatitude();
    this.dragLngOrigin = this.dragLngLast = event.getLongitude();
}
```

The `mousemove` callback updates to the latest lat long coordinates:

```
this.dragMouseMoveCallback = lang.hitch(this, function (event) {
    if (this.dragObject) {
        var lat = event.getLatitude();
        var lng = event.getLongitude();
        var latDiff = lat - this.dragLatLast;
        var lngDiff = lng - this.dragLngLast;
        if (Math.abs(latDiff) > this.dragSensitivity || Math.abs(lngDiff > this.dragSensitivity)) {
            this.addPolyCoords(this.dragObject, [latDiff, lngDiff]);
            this.dragLatLast = lat;
            this.dragLngLast = lng;
        }
    }
});
```

Here I'm using some fancy sensitivity values to prevent updating this too often. Finally, `addPolyCoords` is also my own function which adds lat long values to the existing coordinates of the polygon - effectively moving it across the globe. I do this with the built in `setLatitude()` and `setLongitude()` functions for each coordinate. You can get the coordinates like so, where polygon is a `KmlPolyon` object:

```
polygon.getGeometry().getOuterBoundary().getCoordinates()
```

And of course, the `mousedown` callback turns off the drag mode so that moving the mouse doesn't continue to drag the polygon:

```
this.dragMouseUpCallback = lang.hitch(this, function (event) {
    if (this.dragObject) {
        Log.info('Stop drag', this.dragObject.getType());
        setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.lockCamera(false);
            this.setSelected(null);
        }), 100);
        this._dragEvent(event);
        this.dragObject = this.dragLatOrigin = this.dragLngOrigin = this.dragLatLast = this.dragLngLast = null;
    }
});
```

And finally, `_dragEvent` is called to ensure that the final coordinates are the actual coordinates the mouse event finished with (and not the latest `mousemove` call):

```
_dragEvent: function (event) {
    // summary:
    //      Helper function for moving drag object
    var latDiff = event.getLatitude() - this.dragLatLast;
    var lngDiff = event.getLongitude() - this.dragLngLast;
    if (!(latDiff == 0 && lngDiff == 0)) {
        this.addPolyCoords(this.dragObject, [latDiff, lngDiff]);
        Log.info('Moved ' + latDiff + ', ' + lngDiff);
    }
},
```

The `mousemove` callback isn't too important and can actually be ignored - the only reason I use it is to show the polygon moving as the user moves their mouse. Removing it will result in the object being moved when they lift their mouse up.

Hopefully this incredibly long answer gives you some insights into how to implement dragging in the Google Earth API. And I also plan to release my library in the future when I've ironed out the kinks :)

Comment: wow know you if addPolyCoords exist as geospatial function like st_intersects or st_difference ?